# LENOVO PX12-450R RAID configuration + general advice

Tags: iscsi, network-attached-storage, vmdk

I have a Lenovo PX12-450R NAS device with eight 3TB 7.2rpm drives.
The device has a Quad-Core 2.5GHz Xeon CPU + 8GB DDR3 RAM. I have 4 gigabit NICS bonded. I am looking to use it to be a target for my backups from Veeam, to give my users shares to store their archive files, and possibly use it as a datastore for non-critical VMs. I have two questions:

1. Should I lump everything together and make 1 big RAID 10 storage
   pool and then create volumes for the items above or make two
   separate RAID 10 pools- one for backup and one for VM / file shares.
2. I will be migrating a WIN 2008 R2 file server to 2012 r2. The data VMDK with the file shares is about 1.5 TB. Is it a good idea to
   put that VMDK on an ISCSI datastore from the NAS and then put the OS
   on local storage of the server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Should I lump everything together and make 1 big RAID 10 storage pool and then create volumes for the items above or make two separate RAID 10 pools- one for backup and one for VM / file shares.

A1: Yes, keep one pool and wrap logical volumes on top. If you'd create two separate pools / virtual LUNs you'll split your IOPS between both of them and it's not good. To keep data safe make sure you maintain multiple copies of it. Google for "3-2-1 Backup Plan".

Q2: I will be migrating a WIN 2008 R2 file server to 2012 r2. The data VMDK with the file shares is about 1.5 TB. Is it a good idea to put that VMDK on an ISCSI datastore from the NAS and then put the OS on local storage of the server?

A2: It's better to keep all content on the same place, and make sure this storage is shared. You'll be able to vMotion / Live Migration your VM to some other physical host if required. Splitting data between DAS and NAS only makes management complicated.

Comment: Yup, agree. Just want to expand this answer by dropping few useful links here

Comment: Here is pretty good explanation of 3-2-1 BAclup Rule: https://knowledgebase.starwindsoftware.com/explanation/the-3-2-1-backup-rule/

Comment: On my experience Veeam worked pretty good for backups https://www.veeam.com/

Comment: And StarWind Virtual SAN may be an option for running FT shared storagge https://www.starwindsoftware.com/

Answer (score -2):

We have it that way I have a raid 10 running 8 machines and 2 volumes running backup. so far with very good performance; you can use virtualization to take better advantage of this product.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ricardo! So just to be clear you have one big raid 10 and then different volumes for backup and VM datastore targets?

Comment: I`m sorry, but that doesn`t answer to any of the asked questions